# drop Na from dataframe row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, na

how to drop NAN in df input with pandas to have an list with just values in array

```
**Input**
A |B |C 
-----------
x |y | NA
x |NA| NA
X |Y [ NA
```

**Output**

```
[[x,y],
 [X],
 [x,y]
]
```

it try to pass each row :

```
dataset.apply(lambda row: row[pd.notna(row)],axis=0).to_numpy()

array([["Belkin 325VA UPS Surge Protector, 6'",
        'Master Caster Door Stop, Large Neon Orange',
        'Easy-staple paper', 'Polycom VVX 310 VoIP phone',
        'Acco Banker\'s Clasps, 5 3/4"-Long',
        'Verbatim 25 GB 6x Blu-ray Single Layer Recordable Disc, 1/Pack',
        'Fellowes Advanced Computer Series Surge Protectors',
        'GBC DocuBind 200 Manual Binding Machine',
        'Tenex Personal Project File with Scoop Front Design, Black',
        'Avery Binding System Hidden Tab Executive Style Index Sets',
        'High Speed Automatic Electric Letter Opener', nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
```

can you explain the best approch to do it ?

Comment: Hi!! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
out=df.agg(lambda x:list(x.dropna()),axis=1).tolist()
#you can also use apply() in place of agg() method
#If you need array then instead of tolist() use values attribute or to_numpy() method
out=df.agg(lambda x:list(x.dropna()),axis=1).values
```

output of `out`:

```
[['x', 'y'], ['x'], ['X', 'Y']]
```